# Simple connectedness and local simple connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is it true that any simply connected space is also locally simply connected?

This might look like a dumb question, but when I found out that path-connectedness and local path-connectedness are indipendent properties, I'm asking this question every time I study a new property of topological spaces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_simply_connected_space  "The cone on the Hawaiian earring is contractible and therefore simply connected, but still not locally simply connected."

Comment: There is also another concept, of semi-local simple connectivity. I would expect this one is also independent of local simple connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Pick any space that is not locally simply connected. Then [cone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) over that space is simply connected, even contractible. But it remains not locally simply connected. Because there's a small neighborhood of the bottom such that bottom is its quotient (via projection onto first coordinate). And quotient maps preserve being locally simply connected.